# Using dictation feature to paste text into Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, accessibility, voice-dictation

With user-created dictation commands, it's possible to paste text into an application. I tried creating a voice command that would paste in a text command into Terminal. However, nothing gets pasted. I can see the command get activated because the "Edit" flashes. I am able to paste text into other applications with voice commands without an issue.

Does anyone know of a workaround to this problem?

Comment: Interesting problem, I've just tried it with Sierra 10.12.4 and it works fine for me into Terminal.

Comment: Good to know. I'm on 10.12.5. Hmm. Let me try on another Mac.

Comment: Same problem on other computer with 10.12.4.

Comment: Are you creating a new command with the advanced commands feature to paste in a string of pre-determined text or are you just straight dictating your text into the dictation tool?

Comment: I had copied text manually, switched to Terminal and said "paste that" to paste it in, the edit menu flashed and the text was pasted. I just made my own custom command to paste predefined text, which didn't work exactly like you said, flashing the edit menu but not working, and then subsequent "paste that" also didn't work, until I quit and relaunched Terminal (keeping the same dictation session). Apologies for the confusion, that's a very peculiar bug!

Comment: Damn, I guess my dream of typing long or difficult commands to remember by voice are dashed. Guess it's back to the old bash shell abbreviations for me.

Comment: Same exact bug with iTerm, how odd.

Answer (score 2):

This problem continued for me when I updated to 10.13.3 but I found a solution.  Rather than using the Paste Text option when creating the new Dictation Command, use the Paste Data command.  Then go to TextEdit and type the text you want, select, and copy it.  Then go back to the window creating your Dictation Command and click on the Import from Clipboard button.  You will notice that the button moves down (I assume meaning that there is data there now).  Now my Dictation Command works!  I am not sure if this works in earlier versions of Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure and enhanced dictation is enabled.  You do not need to create a new dictation command.  Just select the text you want to copy to your clipboard and speak the command “copy that” .  Then in the terminal app, just say the command “paste that”

[image]